# Adding components to default vue-cli webpack app

Tags: npm, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

For the sake of reproducibility: First, I created a default project using vue-cli like so:

```
npm install -g vue-cli
vue init webpack spa
cd spa
npm install
npm run dev
```

From there I decided to start by replacing the Vue logo with an app-header component. I wrote the code like so:

[image]

I first created AppHeader.vue in the components folder and gave it a template, export script, and empty style for good measure. It has an element (I've tried with and without it). I imported the AppHeader component in App.vue and used it in the template.

It doesn't show up. The only thing I see is the HelloWorld component in the router-view.

I think I covered all my bases, but does anyone see something I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the component in the file `App.vue`s export statement wrapped as `components` object. Also remove `el` and `name` on `AppHeader.vue`. Then it must be all good to go.

`App.vue`:

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    AppHeader
  }
}
```

`AppHeader.vue`:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Header"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I added that, but no change.

Comment: Sorry I needed to say that you also need to configure your router.

Comment: Sorry to bother. The router is already displaying the HelloWorld component as expected. The examples in the vue-router documentation have content outside the view-router component. The header is likewise outside the view router element the router is bound to. Could you explain how the view router affects the header and what kind of configuration you mean?

Comment: You are right, my bad. Nothing to do with router. Did you use VueJS chrome plugin to see if the component AppHeader is part of the composition?

Comment: Yeah. It isn't. <div class="hello"..> is the first child of the app.

Comment: BTW `el` and `name` properties in the exposed object in AppHeader are not necessary. They may be detrimental (I am speculating, lol). If you look at the documentation `el` and `name` properties are not there for single page components.

Comment: The HelloWorld component has a name. Regardless, that worked for some reason that I don't understand.

Comment: Could you add the removing el and name to your answer? Then I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @AaronF yes, I did it.